# Nginx, one application, many domains, redirect SSL and non-www for all domains

Tags: laravel, ssl, nginx

I have a Laravel app on Nginx which delivers (hosts) many different domains. I need to 301 direct for non-www to www and for http to https.

I have tried so many ways but just cannot make it work. Has anyone got a good example for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

may this will help you

```
server {
    listen 80 example.com;

    server_name *.example.com example.com;
    return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: That looks like it would be fine for http to https including http non-www. But what about https non-www?

Comment: can you describe bit more about what domain you wan to redirect according to my knowledge there will be no prefix www.example.domain.com if domain start with www it means its a main domain and and wildcard domain look like anythi.domain.com

Comment: This app serves multiple domains. But for my example I have www.thebristolartist.tk and www.thebristolgallery.tk. I want them to redirect to www if www is not explicit. And I want them to return the https version. If it helps I can paste my current conf file which is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me:

```
if ($host ~* ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$) {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://www.$host$1 permanent;
}
```